Identify chip with markings IRP517
I am trying to identify an 8-pin SOIC chip with markings IRP 517 C or G .  These are in a decent-size power supply for LED signs.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Please add a picture with all of the markings visible. P517G is likely a traceability code looking at other devices made by International Rectifier.

I will get a better picture when the tech working on this is back in my shop.  Many thanks!

Not sure because the image is blurred but I read in the last line "F7319".
In that case it is a IRF7319 Dual MOSFET from Infineon (International Rectifiers).

Picture from ebay:

